# Eclipse crashed and now R file not generated

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, r.java-file

My project was compiling, and I have no changes in my local repository in XML files. But Eclipse crashed at one point, when I opened it again, the R file wouldn't get generated.

I've tried

- the obligatory clean project,
- obligatory restart eclipse,
- obligatory install latest updates from SDK manager and then installing new Eclipse software updates.

But the R file for this project still won't get generated.

1) There are no error in the XML files that I can see,

2) no XML file changes in my last few commits or local repository,

3) I've deleted the bin and gen folders and they get auto-regenerated just without the R file.

4) I've even reverted my entire project back a few commits to when I know the project was compiling but Eclipse simply won't generate the R file

any suggestions?

Comment: Try closing the project and importing it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are using some Menu on your applications? Something if you have any error in the file menu, your R file doesn't generated

Yesterday i had the same issue

Comment: hey! okay, so I moved the menu folder out of my project and the R files got generated... just the new errors related to menus are there now. thanks

Comment: Great! Have a great coding

Answer (score 0):

did you try to clean your project ? (from project menu then clean ).

does this error appears in a every new hello world project ???

if so, download a new version of eclipse ADT and extract it in a new folder, then test again.

Comment: maybe something about my workspace just needs to be cleaned? like from the command line perhaps